# Forticlient SSL VPN freezes Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: vpn

I have a problem with Forticlient software on Ubuntu 22.04. Every time I manage to connect my VPN, entire system freezes - no keyboard actions work and the screen just freezes. However, the system seems to be running, because there appear another entries in various logs. I have also tried it out in non-GUI mode and everything worked as it should. That makes me think that once VPN tunnel is established, something hangs GNOME. I cannot find any reasonable cause in syslog and dmesg, it just freezes. No matter if I take open Forticlient or the official packet from Fortinet, the effect is always the same.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Would be a good idea to talk to the Fortinet people.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem is fixed. Seems that one of GNOME extensions installed was the culprit. Seems that simply disabling extensions was not enough, I had to disable them and **restart** the computer. Then VPN started to work.

Comment: A complete answer would say the exact extension you had to disable.

Comment: IT had IP in its name, unfortunatelly cannot remind myself an exact name.

Comment: So it stays not an answer.